# Colocar um valor dentro da do 'val' do jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a forma correta de montar essa linha?

```
$("#rastreo").val('BR'<?php echo date("hYmdi"); ?>json[0].estado);
```

O ID rastreo é um campo input.

Comment: "rastreo" é oque ? Pode der mais detalhes. é um input, uma div ?

Comment: Esse campo é um input

Comment: Qual problema está tendo?

Comment: @Marconi não funciona. Impede o carregamento de todos os outros js..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lembre-se de que para concatenar strings com `js` usa-se o caractere '+'. Então seu código original ficaria:

```
$("#rastreo").val('BR'+<?php echo date("hYmdi"); ?>+json[0].estado);
```

Uma forma alternativa pode ser:

```
$('#rastreo').attr('value', 'BR'+<?php echo date("hYmdi"); ?>+json[0].estado);
```

Comment: Pode ser que seja este o erro dele.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Se for um `input` você deve fazer desta forma:

```js
$("#rastreo").val('TESTE');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id ="rastreo"> </input>
```

No caso é da mesma forma que você já esta fazendo hoje. Então acredito que o problema esteja em :

```
<?php echo date("hYmdi"); ?>json[0].estado
```

Comment: Estou ciente. A minha dúvida é como fazer da forma correta, na forma que eu preciso acima.

Comment: Você deve detalhar melhor sua pergunta. Informar qual o retorno de `json[0].estado` por exemplo. E também qual o erro que está ocorrendo, assim podemos te ajudar;